# Virtual Environment Making Astroquery Gaia Search Fail

Tags: python, ssl, astroquery

I am using astroquery to search through the Gaia catalog. However, I am using a MacOS local venv which is causing it to fail. I tested my code without the venv activated and it works as intended. I need to use this virtual environment sadly.

Why does my astroquery code break when using a venv?

Code:

```
def gaia_table(ra, dec, radius): 
  #Makes the SQL code to run it into the GAIA search
  query = "SELECT TOP 2000 \
  gaia_source.ra,gaia_source.dec,gaia_source.ra_error,gaia_source.phot_g_mean_flux_error,gaia_source.phot_bp_mean_flux_error,gaia_source.phot_rp_mean_flux_error,gaia_source.ref_epoch,gaia_source.dec_error,gaia_source.parallax,gaia_source.parallax_error,gaia_source.radial_velocity,gaia_source.radial_velocity_error,gaia_source.pmra,gaia_source.pmra_error,gaia_source.pmdec,gaia_source.pmdec_error,gaia_source.phot_g_mean_mag,gaia_source.phot_bp_mean_mag,gaia_source.phot_rp_mean_mag,gaia_source.phot_g_mean_flux,gaia_source.phot_bp_mean_flux,gaia_source.phot_rp_mean_flux \
  FROM gaiadr3.gaia_source \
  WHERE \
  CONTAINS( \
  POINT('ICRS',gaiadr3.gaia_source.ra,gaiadr3.gaia_source.dec), \
  CIRCLE('ICRS', " + str(ra) + "," + str(dec) + "," + str(((radius/2) * 0.000277778) - 0.000277778)+ ")" \
  ")=1"

  #Run this SQL query on the online GAIA database
  job = Gaia.launch_job_async(query)
  results = job.get_results()
  return results
```

Error:

```
  File "WRAP.py", line 981, in gaia_table
    job = Gaia.launch_job_async(query)
  File "/Users/Documents/GitHub/WRAP/wrap_mac/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroquery/gaia/core.py", line 903, in launch_job_async
    return TapPlus.launch_job_async(self, query=query,
  File "/Users/Documents/GitHub/WRAP/wrap_mac/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroquery/utils/tap/core.py", line 409, in launch_job_async
    response = self.__launchJob(query,
  File "/Users/Documents/GitHub/WRAP/wrap_mac/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroquery/utils/tap/core.py", line 625, in __launchJob
    response = self.__connHandler.execute_tappost(subcontext=context,
  File "/Users/Documents/GitHub/WRAP/wrap_mac/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroquery/utils/tap/conn/tapconn.py", line 273, in execute_tappost
    return self.__execute_post(context, data, content_type, verbose)
  File "/Users/Documents/GitHub/WRAP/wrap_mac/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroquery/utils/tap/conn/tapconn.py", line 426, in __execute_post
    conn.request("POST", context, data, self.__postHeaders)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 950, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1424, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1125)
```